# Python Turtle: Starting Countdown gets stuck

Tags: python, timer, countdown, turtle-graphics

I am making a dodging game in which the turtle (shaped like a turtle) has to avoid other turtles (shaped like crocodiles). I got the game working but am trying to add in a countdown before the game starts which goes 3,2,1,GO!

My thinking is that since the countdown_number variable I have goes 3, 2, 1, and then GO!, I can get it to come before the rest of the game by having everything else dependent on the value of the countdown_number being "GO!".

Right now, however, when I start the program it gets stuck on 3 and after the update interval starts over again instead of continuing through 2, 1, and GO! so the game cannot start.

I've seen a lot of questions on Stack Overflow that have to do with running timers and things concurrent to the game but I need this to occur before the game starts.

```
import turtle
import random
import pygame

window_height = 600
window_width = 600

update_interval = 25

countdown_number = 3

river_width = 400
minimum_river_width = 200

border_height = 600

river_width_update = 0.5

safe_distance_from_border = border_height / 2 + 3

number_of_enemies = 10
enemies = []
enemy_speeds = []
enemy_width = 100
enemy_height = 40
enemy_speed_min, enemy_speed_max = 10, 20

safe_distance_from_enemy = 15

def startgame():
    global countdown_number
    if countdown_number >= 1:
        turtle.home()
        turtle.left(270)
        turtle.clear()
        turtle.speed(0)
        for _ in range(0,100,5):
            turtle.forward(1)
            turtle.color("grey"+str(_))
            turtle.write(countdown_number, align="center", font=("Arial", 200, "normal"))
    if countdown_number == 0:
        countdown_number = "GO!"
        turtle.home()
        turtle.left(270)
        turtle.clear()
        turtle.speed(0)
        for _ in range(0,100,5):
            turtle.forward(1)
            turtle.color("grey"+str(_))
            turtle.write(countdown_number, align="center", font=("Arial", 200, "normal"))
        turtle.clear()

    #print(number)

def gameover(msg):
    print(msg) # Probably comment this out later
    turtle.home()
    turtle.write(msg, align="center", font=("Arial", 24, "normal"))

def moveplayerturtle(x, y):
    if x > -window_width / 2 and x < window_width / 2:
        turtle.goto(x, y)

def updatescreen():

    global river_width
    global countdown_number
    if countdown_number != "GO!":
        startgame()

    if countdown_number == "GO!":

        if upper_river_border.ycor() >= window_height-200:
            upper_river_border.sety(upper_river_border.ycor() - river_width_update)

        if lower_river_border.ycor() <= -window_height+200:
            lower_river_border.sety(lower_river_border.ycor() + river_width_update)

        if upper_river_border.ycor() - turtle.ycor() < safe_distance_from_border:

            gameover("Game over!")

            return
        if turtle.ycor() - lower_river_border.ycor() < safe_distance_from_border:

            gameover("Game over!")

            return

        for i in range(number_of_enemies):

            enemies[i].forward(enemy_speeds[i])

            if enemies[i].xcor() > (window_width+enemy_width)/2:
                x = -(window_width+enemy_width)/2
                y = int(turtle.ycor())
                enemies[i].goto(x, y)
                s=1
                enemy_speeds[i]=int(random.randrange(10+s, 20+s))

            if turtle.distance(enemies[i]) < safe_distance_from_enemy:
                gameover("You lose!")
                return

    turtle.ontimer(updatescreen, update_interval)
    turtle.update()

turtle.setup(window_width, window_height) # Set the window size
turtle.bgcolor("DarkBlue")

turtle.tracer(False)

upper_river_border = turtle.Turtle()
upper_river_border.up()
lower_river_border = turtle.Turtle()
lower_river_border.up()

upper_river_border.shape("square")
lower_river_border.shape("square")

upper_river_border.color("DarkOrange4")
lower_river_border.color("DarkOrange4")

upper_river_border.shapesize(30, 40)
lower_river_border.shapesize(30, 40)

upper_river_border.sety((border_height + river_width) / 2)
lower_river_border.sety(-(border_height + river_width) / 2)

turtle.addshape("crocodile.gif")

for _ in range(number_of_enemies):

    enemy = turtle.Turtle()

    turtle.addshape("crocodile.gif")
    enemy.shape("crocodile.gif")
    enemy.up()
    x = -(window_width + enemy_width) / 2
    y = random.randint(-(river_width-enemy_height)/2, (river_width-enemy_height)/2)
    enemy.goto(x, y)

    enemies.append(enemy)

    enemy_speeds.append(random.randint(enemy_speed_min, enemy_speed_max))

turtle.shape("turtle")
turtle.left(180)
turtle.color("GreenYellow")
turtle.up()

turtle.ondrag(moveplayerturtle)

turtle.ontimer(updatescreen, update_interval)

turtle.done()
```

I've gotten the countdown to work perfectly fine on its own when I've written it as it's own program so I think it must just have to do with transitioning from the countdown sequence to the game loop itself that's causing the problem.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You've got your wires crossed as far as the splash screen countdown -- calling the wrong thing at the wrong time.  Below's my suggestion on a minimal fix.  First, redefine `startgame()` as follows:

```
def startgame():
    global countdown_number

    turtle.home()
    turtle.clear()
    turtle.left(270)

    if countdown_number > 0:
        for grey in range(0, 100, 5):
            turtle.forward(1)
            turtle.color("grey" + str(grey))
            turtle.write(countdown_number, align="center", font=("Arial", 200, "normal"))

        countdown_number -= 1

        turtle.ontimer(startgame, countdown_interval)

    else:
        for grey in range(0, 100, 5):
            turtle.forward(1)
            turtle.color("grey" + str(grey))
            turtle.write("GO!", align="center", font=("Arial", 200, "normal"))

        turtle.clear()

        turtle.ontimer(updatescreen, countdown_interval)
```

Next some small changes to accomodate this rewrite.  At the top of your code, add the definition:

```
countdown_interval = 1000
```

near the definition of `update_interval`.

At the bottom of your code, instead of this:

```
turtle.ontimer(updatescreen, update_interval)

turtle.done()
```

Do this:

```
turtle.ontimer(startgame, update_interval)

turtle.done()
```

Finally, in `updatescreen()` remove all code dealing with `countdown_number`:

```
global countdown_number
if countdown_number != "GO!":
    startgame()

if countdown_number == "GO!":
```

and reindent the body of this function as needed.

That should do it.  Happy dodging!